# Laravel redirect exception not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have problem, I can't redirect this exception:

```
This action is unauthorized.
```

In handler I have:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
...

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

But condition always return false.. Why?

I get message in debug:

```
protected function prepareException(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    **} elseif ($e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
        $e = new AccessDeniedHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);**
    } elseif ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        $e = new HttpException(419, $e->getMessage(), $e);
    }

    return $e;
}
```

I tryied and `AccessDeniedHttpException`. Not working...

Comment: you can use `get_class($exception)` to get the name of the class you have to use in your condition

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ Is right, you first need to know for sure which type of Exception is thrown. It probably is one you are not expecting ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception:

> This action is unauthorized.

Is caused by `Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;`

Therefore, your function should be like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
...

public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

The one you are currently using (`Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException`) is for authentications.